# What are the steps to create a texture from an array in Vulkan?

Tags: textures, vulkan

I have a 2D array (256x16) that I need to load into a Vulkan style texture to sample from. In OpenGL, this would be accomplished simply enough with glTexImage2D or glTexSubImage2D. However, I don't know how to do the same thing in Vulkan.

The array is defined as follows:

```
static const int triTable[256][16] =
{ { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
{ 0, 8, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
...
...
{ 0, 3, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
{ -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 } };
```

Comment: What does a value of -1 mean? Actually, it's not clear what these values mean at all. Are these RGBA colors, is this a one-channel image? What format of texture are you trying to create?

Comment: This is a list of voxel edges which require a vertex under the marching cubes algorithm for terrain generation. Each 16 length list contains 0-12 numbers representing these edges. A -1 is just a null value, and there are 16 values to hold to a power of two width (I assume, as I did not create this list). They will be represented in the image in one channel (Red).

Comment: And what bitdepth do you want to upload this texture as? Do you want an integer format or a floating-point format? What VK_FORMAT do you intend to use?

Comment: For the format: VK_FORMAT_R32_SINT should work.

Not sure about bit depth. Unless the bit depth is the R32 part of that format.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create appropriate USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC VkBuffer (or TILING_LINEAR USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC VkImage is also possible to be used, but is less canonical way).
2. Query memory requirements of it. Then Allocate it based on that in a Host visible memory and Bind that memory to the Buffer (or Image).
3. Map the memory. Copy your data (observing `vkGetImageSubresourceLayout()` info if you chosen to use Image). Unmap the memory.
4. Copy the data into your final desired (idealy optimalized) VkImage by `vkCmdCopyBufferToImage()` (or `vkCmdCopyImage()`).
5. Done. Some synchronization and other boilerplate may be necessary in there...

If you are unsure, just hijack someone elses code, e.g. https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan

Comment: You missed the part where you have to query how much memory you need for your optimally tiled image and to create that image and attach it to the appropriate memory. And it's better to use buffers for staging than linearly tiled images.

Comment: a)Yes, I treated it as external code/already existing (haven't even created it). b) Probably so, I just dislike it, because it slices semantics, and I didn't find much advantage in it. I guess I will edit the answer...

Comment: Trust me, I'm hijacking everything I can from Sascha. I just can't seem to wrap my head around the process behind creating textures I guess. Plus the "synchronization and boilerplate" you mentioned isn't stuff I've fully understood yet.

Comment: Well it's the point, where it gets awfully specific, and I would need to see yer code. ;; Vulkan just doesn't hide it under all-powerful function. Process is pretty much: transfer raw memory data to GPU and bind it to Image which is like interface, that interprets the data as texture. Don't overthink it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create VkImage then getMemoryRequirements, allocate memory and
   vkBindImageMemory.
2. Fill the contents by mapping this memory.
3. Create a command buffer and record it for transforming layout of
   image and submit it.
4. Create Sampler and image view from image.

I have a code here [link](https://github.com/Vittalbabu/GearVRf/blob/builtinshaders/GVRf/Framework/framework/src/main/jni/vulkan/vulkanCore.cpp)

Check for functions: InitTexture and CreateSampler